# subprocess stdout not receiving all output

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to create a script which will run a program, then run a second program to get the logs from the first, and wait until it receives a specific log entry before continuing.

This is what I have so far:

```
log_process = subprocess.Popen(["/system/bin/logcat", "-T10", "-s", "SetupReceiver:I"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
call_am("start_setup")
while True:
    for line in iter(log_process.stdout.readline, "_exit_string_"):
        logger.debug("{0} found in logcat".format(line))
        if "Automatic setup succeeded" in line:
            # Setup complete
            log_process.kill()
            break
        elif "Automatic setup failed" in line:
            # Setup failed
            disable_device("TV Setup Failed")
            log_process.kill()
            break
```

The script successfully starts both programs, and prints the first few log messages in it's debug. However it then stops and doesn't output any more of the logs.

Why are the logs not being detected, and how can I make the script work?

Comment: There are problems with the implementation of readline (and more), see for example https://bugs.python.org/issue1633941.
I had that kind of problem with elpy on Emacs, who usually hangs after "some time" in readline when connected to a "slow" pipe, under "some" versions of Python.
Have you tried with Python3? It seems that things work much better with it (and I personnaly don't remember running into problems using it.)

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Unfortunately Python 3 isn't available for the platform I'm developing for :(

Comment: Problem solved for me. Other users had the same problem I had only when they were *not* in a virtualenv. I finally managed to get everything working fine, either 1) by using virtualenvs (created with pyenv, which compiles python from source) or 2) by using a python compiled from source (I used the latest 2.7.13) instead of the original (2.7.6) of my Ubuntu installation. Still don't really know where the problem lies, though...